# mysql query: searching based on all values in column rather than one value in column

Tags: mysql

```
select address
from properties.tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping  a
INNER JOIN properties.tblproperty b ON a.propertyid = b.propertyid
where propertyassetclassid =2;
```

This is the query that I have as of now. We can focus on this particular portion of the query `and propertyassetclassid = 2`. I would like to execute this query for all values in propertyassetclassid[there are 25 random values in this column]. Instead of ANDing each value like

```
   and propertyassetclassid = 4
   and propertyassetclassid = 5
   and propertyassetclassid = 6
```

I feel like there should be an easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work if the value begins from 1 and ends in 25:

```
select address
    from properties.tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping  a
    INNER JOIN properties.tblproperty b ON a.propertyid = b.propertyid
    where propertyassetclassid BETWEEN '1' AND '25';
```

Comment: what happens if it is random values?

Answer (score 1):

As I know may be you want like this

```
select address
    from properties.tblpropertyassetclass_property_mapping  a
    INNER JOIN properties.tblproperty b ON a.propertyid = b.propertyid
    where propertyassetclassid is not null
```